# What color is the font of the item of Listview in Android?

Tags: android

I create a listview control with customize item, I wonder what color the font of the item of Listview in Android is? is it black? I'm not sure.

Where can I define the color of the item of Listview? Thanks!

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>    
</resources>



android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1" 
}
```

**cleanup_logs.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListViewLog"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
     />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnExport"
            style="@style/myTextSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/BtnExport" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEmpty"
            style="@style/myTextSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/BtnEmpty" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReturn"
            style="@style/myTextSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/BtnReturn" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**my_listview_adapter_log.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:text="@string/SmsName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/LeftPaddingInLog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:text="@string/SmsDate" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/LeftPaddingInLog"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:text="@string/SmsType" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/LeftPaddingInLog"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="18dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:text="@string/SmsBody" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBody"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/LeftPaddingInLog"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in textview xml, you can define text color by adding `android:textColor="@color/white"`

Comment: The default color depends on the theme you apply. You can change it, though. By either changing the theme or using a custom row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of the font of the item in the listview is by default white if u use predefined layouts for the textview.

That is why we have to set the background color of the listview as black(#000) to view the contents.That is if you are using predefined layouts

```
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),R.array.cities,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

But important point to note that if you want to change the color of the item in the list view, you have to make your own layout xml file where you define a single text view and then change color there of the text view, say your xml file is called "ABC". The last parameter is what i am talking about.

```
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),R.array.cities,R.layout.ABC);
```

Feel free for any queries.

Comment: Thanks! it seems that the color of the font of the item in the listview isn not by default white because I have set ListView background asandroid:background="#FFFFFF"

Comment: @HelloCW It is white when u use predefined layout for the textview, by default i mean android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Comment: @HelloCW I will elaborate. The color of the item of the listview is decided by the textview color which is contained in the layout file which we pass as last parameter when we are initializing the adapter. If you use predefined layout as mentioned in my answer the color will be white, This is what i am saying.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder what color the font of the item of Listview in Android is? is it black? I'm not sure

Look into sources. Or take the screenshot, use Gimp/color picker etc and find out?

> Where can I define the color of the item of Listview? Thanks!

In row layout.

Comment: Thanks! I have set "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar", I hope to find the default color of the item in listview from source code, but I don't know what source code I sould to search

Answer (score 0):

> Adapter is the place where you decide how the data should be binded in  ListView. So Just do the color changes in your adapter. Mention the color in your TextViews. In this sample, font_color is the color mentioned in color.xml
>
> **my_listview_adapter_log.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:textColor="@color/font_color" 
            android:text="@string/SmsName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/LeftPaddingInLog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/font_color" 
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! In my code, I don't set  android:textColor="@color/font_color" , so it will display system defined color, I wonder what kind of color is used

Comment: Actually, 'System defined' implies the theme in which you are using. You can create your own style items in 'styles.xml'  inside 'res/values' folder and provide custom styling.